# Database design & implementation in Laravel - Auto increments that are bound to individual rows, not just one table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, laravel, multi-tenant

I have a question that can be answered either theoretically or empirically, depending on whether this has been fully accomplished before or not.

I have a web application that I am building which can house multiple clients, all who have their own separated sets of data. One particular function of this software is **invoicing**.

With this, each invoice you create will increment by 1, so normally we would apply an AUTO_INCREMENT field to the id. The problem however comes when we start to introduce the multiple client functionality.

Allow me to demonstrate the issue through example:

> Client A makes his first sale, and creates an invoice for this which automatically has an ID of 1. By the time the sale was processed, he had made his second sale. When he creates his second invoice, he notices that something is wrong with the invoice numbering. His second invoice now has the ID of 3.
>
> The reason for this is because Client B, recently having signed up to the system, has created his first sale, which had an ID of 2. Now both clients have incorrect invoice numbering, and this has very quickly become an unworkable solution

I have had to add a table called **invoice_client_increments** which is essentially a pivot between the invoice and the client, which stores the new increment. While this works, it feels very messy to work with.

When creating the invoice, I have to pull the last **invoice_client_increments** record for that client and add one to it, insert another one and associate it to the invoice. If one deletes an invoice, that increment is lost and it will not behave as increments normally would, it would instead overwrite the removed one when an invoice was created.

Is there a better way to design a database to accommodate this, and an easier way to implement this into Laravel, or am I doing this how it should be done already? This may be more of a question of best practice rather than "How do I do this?"... Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I can't see the problem, what's wrong with having different IDs ?

Comment: Clients will want their invoicing systems to start from 1 and to have no gaps for legal reasons. If there were 300 clients and one created their first invoice as invoice 1489 and their second one as 5930, it would make no sense and confuse the client.

Comment: I dropped the "php" tag and added "multi-tenant", which might help draw more attention from the multi-tenant experts. This isn't a php problem.

Answer (score 1):

> With this, each invoice you create will increment by 1, so normally we would apply an AUTO_INCREMENT field to the id.

DBAs would *not* normally do this.

Financial apps usually have to account for every invoice number. Automatically incrementing ID numbers on *all* platforms are *guaranteed* to have gaps under certain circumstances (typically, rollback with concurrent insert statements). You can't account for gaps by simply saying, "Oh, there must have been a rollback."

There are two broad ways to approach your problem.

- Use a Laravel method or a stored procedure to return the next invoice number for a given client. Pay close attention to transaction isolation levels and locking.
- [Change the architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx). Sharing tables is one kind of multi-tenant architecture. It's not the only kind, and it's often not the best choice. When you're reading this linked article, keep in mind that a MySQL database behaves more like a SQL Server schema than a SQL Server database.

Comment: The second solution has a lot of value in it, and proposes an entirely different approach to the database design. A skim through the article has opened a lot of doorways, and I will respond properly once I have read it all and taken it in, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

my freind look you can create a system like this one colum will be auto increment, you dont have to create another cleint_increment table if you dont want to. if you want you can do some think like this

like your auto increment is fine, but when your cleint submit is sale his sale should increase by one, and your invoice number may look like this. incrementNo/CleintReference/CleintsaleNo.

what the cleint sale no. does is add 1 each time when he submit his sale, it does not start when he started the sale, this way you will know which sale is which cleint and your cleint will know how many sale he or she did today.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found the solution and is not to late here's what I did for one app.

I was getting all orders from that particular client, count them and then increase that number by one, like this you always start for each client the count from 0 and then increase it 1.

e.g.

`$totalOrders = DB::table('orders')->where('client_id', $id)->count();'`

```
DB::table('invoices')->insert(array('client_id' =>  $id, 'invoice_no' => ($totalOrders + 1)));
```

I hope this will help you :)